# How to post a Array using Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

hello frieds this is how i usually post a variable using Jquery..

```
$.post("include/save_legatee.inc.php", { legatee_name: legatee_name_string,
                                            legatee_relationship:legatee_relationship_string,                                               
                                                            }, function(response){

                                                                alert(response);

                                                            });
```

Can anybody explain how to post an array using Jquery..

```
   var all_legattee_list= new Array();
  all_legattee_list[1]="mohit";
  all_legattee_list[2]="jain";
```

this is my array... How can post this using jquery???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.post(
    'include/save_legatee.inc.php', 
    { all_legattee_list: ['mohit', 'jain'] }, 
    function(data) {

    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Post this as a string separated with some delimiter.

use **[.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Join)** to join the array

```
var strJoinedArray = all_legattee_list.join(',');
```

and in your php code split the string using `,` and retrieve the values.

Comment: Works only if array elements cannot contain the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `all_legattee_list[]` as name of your parameter, something like this:

```
$.post("...", "all_legattee_list[]=mohit&all_legattee_list[]=jain", ...);
```

Comment: dude i dont know abt the length of the  array(it can be from 10, max).. i m havin  4 arrays that i have to post.. dont u thing this is insane way to do that...

Comment: I don't see how many arrays you have, for simple few elements it's not that bad to do, for many - maybe try using 'all_legattee_list[]' as element name in params object? my example was just a tip what kind of param name you need to use so PHP would use it as array...

Answer (score 0):

For example, like this: [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery). Of course the server would have to support JSON deserialization, but many server-side languages already do.